# Is the puts function of ruby a method of an object?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand how the `puts` function fits in Ruby's "Everything is an object" stance.

Is `puts` is the method of a somehow hidden class/object? Or is it a free-floating method, with no underlying object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand how the `puts` function fits in Ruby's "Everything is an object" stance.

First off, `puts` is not a function. It's *sole purpose* is to have a side-effect (printing something to the console), whereas functions *cannot* have side-effects … that's the *definition* of "function", after all.

Ruby doesn't have functions. It only has methods. Thus, `puts` is a method.

> Is `puts` is the method of a somehow hidden class/object?

No, it's just [a boring old instance method of a boring old class](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Kernel%3aputs). (Well, a boring old instance method of [a boring old mixin](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Kernel), actually, but [a mixin is just a class which abstracts over its superclass](http://Bracha.Org/jigsaw.ps).)

`Kernel` is mixed into `Object`, which is the (default) superclass of all objects (modulo `BasicObject`, of course), thus, `Kernel` is a common superclass (or "supermixin", if you prefer) of (almost) all objects in Ruby.

> Or is it a free-floating method, with no underlying object?

There is no such thing. A method is always associated with an object (the receiver of the message), that's what makes it a "method". (At least in OO parlance. In ADT-oriented languages, the word "method" means something slightly different.)

By the way, the easiest option is always to just ask Ruby herself:

```
method(:puts).owner
# => Kernel
```

Comment: ... functions can have side-effects. They're called impure functions.

Comment: Thanks, very enlightening. I should have used the word sub-routine instead of function, I understand this was misleading.